# Chartjs doughnut with multiple dataset issue in legend creation

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using chartjs & creating a donut chart with multiple datasets. So I have to show individual labels & also the legends.

There was some issue in displaying labels for multiple datasets so I used a hack from [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3953). 
However, I have to show legends as well & I am unable to show it properly.

Here's my fiddle of what i have tried.
https://jsfiddle.net/pyva3fos/

**HTML :**

```
<div id="canvas-holder" style="width:100%">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400" />
</div>
```

**Script :**

```
 var ctx = $("#myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["Market ", "J1", "J2","Market","J share"],
      datasets: [{
        data: [61, 11,27],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#00205A',
          '#97BAFF',
          '#D9D9D9'
        ],
        labels: [
          'Market Share',
          'J1', 
          'J2'
        ]
      }, {
        data: [61, 39],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#00205A',
          '#747474',          
        ],
        labels: [
          'Market Share ',
          'J Share', 
        ],
      }, ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position:'bottom'
      },
      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
            var index = tooltipItem.index;
            return dataset.labels[index] + ': ' + dataset.data[index];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used the [legendCallback](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends) function to create a separate legend.
https://jsfiddle.net/ztnb3h7y/

**HTML :**

```
<div id="canvas-holder" style="width:100%">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400" />
</div>

<div id="chartjs-legend" style="width:100%;" >
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.Mylegend { list-style: none; }

.Mylegend li { float: left; margin-right: 10px; }

.Mylegend span
{ border: 1px solid #ccc; float: left; width: 15px; height: 12px; margin: 2px; }
```

**JS :**

```
function containsObject(obj, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].label == obj.label ) {        
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var ctx = $("#myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ["Market ", "J1", "J2","Market","J Share"],
      datasets: [{
        data: [61, 11,27],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#00205A',
          '#97BAFF',
          '#D9D9D9',
          '#00205A',
          '#747474',          
        ],
        labels: [
          'Market Share',
          'J1', 
          'J2'
        ]
      }, {
        data: [61, 39],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#00205A',
          '#747474',          
        ],
        labels: [
          'Market Share',
          'J Share', 
        ],
      }, ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      showAllTooltips: true,
       legendCallback: function(chart) {
    var text = [];
    var legs = [];
    for( var j=0; j<chart.data.datasets.length;j++)
    {
      for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets[j].data.length; i++) 
      {
          var newd = { label: chart.data.datasets[j].labels[i] , color: chart.data.datasets[j].backgroundColor[i]  };

          if( !containsObject (newd,legs) )
          {
           legs.push(newd);
          }          
       } 
    }

    text.push('<ul class="Mylegend ' + chart.id + '-legend">');
    for( var k =0;k<legs.length;k++)
    {
     text.push('<li><span style="background-color:' + legs[k].color + '"></span>');
    text.push(legs[k].label);
    text.push('</li>');    
    }    
    text.push('</ul>');
    return text.join("");
  },    
      legend: {
        display: false,        
      },
      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
            var index = tooltipItem.index;
            return dataset.labels[index] + ': ' + dataset.data[index];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });


  $("#chartjs-legend").html(myChart.generateLegend());
```